# white-space:nowrap; issue

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-tables

I have a table inside of a div, the div width is 100% and table width is 200% with overflow auto. Now the normal behavior is: when the table is displayed user must scroll to right in order to see all table columns.

If I want to set for table th class `white-space:nowrap;` the div will take a width bigger that ruin my form.

```
table.grid tr th {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example before adding `white-space:nowrap`:
http://tabletest.orgfree.com/

Example after adding `white-space:nowrap`:
http://s7.postimage.org/6rw2idlmj/test.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
td.offersContent {
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 83pc;
    *position: absolute;
    display: block;*
 }
```

this will fix your problem.

Comment: Nice solution, but I dont understand the meaning of **``*``**, the fact is, it works for me.

Comment: That "*" is an ie7 hack used to help ie to render correctly the css properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a wrapper to limit the 100% width

see my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eDVsN/3/)
 i updated the link

Comment: @burebistaruler hi see my example

Comment: yes but I don't understand how can help me, if you have checked my examples you see that in first example all content is on <body> normally and after white-space:nowrap; the body of page is expanding and I don't want that... and I don't need scroll for body page.

Comment: I like to have a size in % because If I put a fixed size I will have problems with lower or bigger resolution of other laptops. will look different :(

Comment: hi try using 98% for your div. i think the scroll bar is messing with your width.. look at the example. i updated it

Comment: If I will do that will drag back only table but not the entire hierarchy td class="offersContent", if you edit with firebug see the form border, this must be on body and not expanded outside off.